# Ordenar de manera ascendente con arrenge()

Tags: r, ordenar, ascendente

¿Cómo puedo ordenar de manera ascendente los datos en R con la función arrenge()?

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar de "menor a mayor" o "mayor a menor" debes usar el mismo comando arrange, de la siguiente forma:

1. Menor a mayor: arrange(bdd, variable)
2. Mayor a menor: arrange(bdd, desc(variable))

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).